# How to get same section index titles as in Contacts app on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

I am building an iOS app and I am using information from the Addressbook. I am displaying all data just as it is in addressbook plus a little custom information but I have a little problem.

My problem is with the section index Titles. First I tried returning an array of all alphabets but it makes my work looks really wierd. I want to have my section index titles in my app to look just the same way it is in the Contacts app with the blue dots as in the image below

Sorry I couldnt upload the image it said i needed 10 rep to do so

Again I repeat , I want my app to have the same section index titles with the blue dots in it just like the Contacts app.

Thank you

This is my code

```
NSArray *alphabets =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",@"M",@"N",@>"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z", nil];

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
      return alphabets;
}
```

Link to image is http://tinypic.com/r/70u93s/5

Comment: show us your code that didn't work

Comment: please add a link to the image

Comment: The index bar is dynamic - it changes based on how many sections there are in the table, and what their section title is. With this in mind, if your contacts only has 2 sections, A and F, then the index bar will only show A and F and will space them with blue dots if you have enough entries in the section to warrant the spacing.

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look at

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html

section Populating an Indexed List.

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionIndexTitles];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if ([[self.states objectAtIndex:section] count] > 0) {

    return [[[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionTitles] objectAtIndex:section];

}

return nil;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help , I tried to put this in my code but it didn't work , I am able to build the code with no errors but when I attempt to run the program it crashes with errors. I have attached a link to a picture which describes what I am looking for. Thank You